# How can I get all the data between a certain amount of year? For example I need the data between 1970-2010

Tags: r, rstudio, subset

I am creating a graph that shows the progression of life expectancy as well as the cost of medical care between a certain set of years in different countries (1970-2010), but I can't find a way to get just the data between those specified years. 
Also here is a link to view the data set if that helps any: https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/life-expectancy-vs-health-expenditure

```
data <- read.csv("file:///C:/Users/Gavyn Henderson/Downloads/life-expectancy-vs-health-expenditure.csv")

names(data) <- c("Country","CountryABV","Year","LifeExpextancy","Expenditure","Population")

data$Expenditure    <- as.numeric(levels(data$Expenditure))[data$Expenditure]


sub1 <- subset(data, CountryABV == "USA"|CountryABV == "GBR"|CountryABV == "DEU"|CountryABV == "FRA"|
                 CountryABV == "JPN"|CountryABV == "AUS"|CountryABV == "CHE"|CountryABV == "CAN")
sub2 <- subset(data, Year %in% 1970:2010)

gg <- ggplot(sub1) + aes(Expenditure, LifeExpextancy,frame = sub2, color = Country) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Population)) + xlab("Life Expectance") + 
  ylab("Health Expenditure") +
  ggtitle("Life Expectance vs. Health Expenditure") +
  ylim(65,85) + 
  xlim(0,8000)
ggplotly(gg)
```

Comment: If you could post a sample of the data, that could help to reproduce the error. By the way, shouldn´t `ggplot(sub1)` be `ggplot(sub2)`

Comment: If `sub2` is your subset data, then this is most likely a typo where you're plotting the wrong data frame

Comment: I agree with @camille ... and add that it might work to use `Year %in% 1970:2010`, but if ever you're dealing with `numeric` instead of `integer` values, you might do better with `1970 <= Year & Year <= 2010` or `between(Year, 1970, 2010)`, where `between` is defined in both `dplyr` and `data.table` (I prefer the latter's implementation, as it accepts vectors in all arguments).

Comment: I added a few changed to my question hopefully that clears up some confusion.